# How to solve the problem that mac conflicts with dl4j?

Tags: java, dl4j

This is all error code:

```
19:09:34.464 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend - Loaded [CpuBackend] backend
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff65aa2aa8, pid=2020, tid=3843
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc++abi.dylib+0x10aa8]  __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info::has_unambiguous_public_base(__cxxabiv1::__dynamic_cast_info*, void*, int) const+0x4
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/mac/Downloads/RL_DQN(19.9.27)/hs_err_pid2020.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

How can I solve this problem?

I found that it without error in this type windows: thinkpad X1 carbon 2021; Windows 10 Enterprise Edition.

It shows error in mac:

- macOS Catalina version10.15.7
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- cpu 2.9 GHz doublecore Intel Core i5 memory 8GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- graphics card Intel Iris Graphics 550 1536MB
- serial number FVFZ18GLL40Y

I replace the dl4j version, but it doesn't work.

I guess mac has incompatibility with dl4j, but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: *"An error report file with more information is saved as..."* have you checked that log?

Comment: https://github.com/adoptium/temurin-build/issues/1315 and https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8249866 --- especially the first link, as they are using dl4j as well. They link to [dl4j bug](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues/8156) where they mention `1.0.0-beta6` as dl4j version which fixes this issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version (beta6 is pretty old at this point). Native crashes should never happen.

Please file an issue at https://gitHub.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues if you still have issues after upgrading to 1.0.0-M2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question.

This is the method: https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/issues/37

I just replace my java version. I use this: jdk1.8.0_311

Original version is: 1.8.0_60

---

<sub>This was originally added to [revision 4 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72993155/4).</sub>